# Generate string from digist and alpha

Tags: python

I have the following list, which contains the characters a-z, 0-9:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
     'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
     'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
     '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

I'm trying to build another string of length 32, by the following logic:

1. Send post request to my server with 'a'
2. If the response flag is True append 'a' to my final string and start again over the list (from a)

Here's an example:

```
POST with data='a' => response.Flag == true => finalString ='a'
POST with data='aa' => response.Flag == false => finalString ='a'
POST with data='ab' => response.Flag == true => finalString ='ab'
......
POST with data='abe751860f6f4e123a927b074d5ffdd2' => response.Flag == true => finalString ='abe751860f6f4e123a927b074d5ffdd2'
```

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(32):
    # How does the inner loop should be?
    tmp = s[i]

    r = requests.post("http://localhost/getFlag", headers=headers, data=tmp)

    if r.json()['Flag'] == True:
        finalString += tmp
```

But how do I implement the inner loop?

Comment: So you want to go through every character at each iteration until you hit a match?

Comment: The algorithm you're describing is much simpler than the one demonstrated in your example. (You should have used one of the words *for* or *each* to describe how you're looping.) If you take the time to express this algorithm in natural language, you'll know a lot more about how to express it in Python.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes!

Comment: @jpaugh. OP's start was fine. What magical simplification did you have in mind?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't know what *start* you're talking about. I'm saying that the English description of the algorithm is oversimplified, and incomplete. It would be easier to develop the algorithm in English before trying to code it in Python.

Comment: @jpaugh. Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to start with the empty string and try every element until one works. Then you want to do the same thing with the character you found as a prefix, etc.:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

s = ascii_lowercase + digits
prefix = ''
for loop in range(32):
    for c in s:
        r = requests.post("http://localhost/getFlag", headers=headers, data=prefix + c)
        if r.json()['Flag']:
            prefix += c
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'failed to find match for character #{loop}')
final_string = prefix
```

Using `else` in the `for` loop allows you to handle the case where no match was found, since an `else` clause executes when the loop runs to completion. A `break` when a match is found prevents the `else` clause form executing.

I've also made your definition of `s` a bit simpler. You can still wrap it in `list`, but a string iterates just as well.

Comment: How can I start from the begin if the Flag is true, I mean if "a" is correct I want to send 'aa' not 'ab'

Comment: Print the post data and you'll see